# AngularJS localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am new to AngularJS. I have a bit difficulty in clearing my localStorage items. I tried clearing using localStorage.clear() or by using return localStorage = null, Still it is not getting cleared. Here is my sample code for signout.

```
$rootScope.signout = function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    $http.get('auth/signout');
    $location.path('/auth/login');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use it like that

```
app.controller('YourController',function(..., $window)
```

then

```
$window.localStorage.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you inject `$localStorage`, or how your `localStorage` variable is defined, but you can clean your local storage with:

Using [`ngStorage`](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage):

```
$localStorage.$reset();
```

Using `$window`:

```
$window.localStorage.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `$window.localStore.removeItem('key');`

where 'key' is the name of the property you want to delete from the localStorage.

If doesn't work please write your full code and maybe I can help you better.